# Array deletion taking place from the lower index first?

Tags: java, android

My app is in the foreground. and there are 2 items into a recyclerview list. whenever I delete my 2nd item from the list and after that click on the 1st item my app gets crash. and in Logcat I get the error like - `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`. But when I delete 1st item from my list and after that click on the remaining 2nd item my app works fine.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    onClick.onItemCli(position, banners.get(position));
}
```

I tried out by doing position -1 in this method like the below code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    onClick.onItemCli(position-1, banners.get(position-1));
}
```

but by this case my app is crashing whenever there are 2 items in list and i click on 2nd item.

The error I am getting is :

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1

```
public class HeaderSliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HeaderSliderAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public List<Banner> banners;
    public Context context;
    private OnItemClicked onClick;


    public HeaderSliderAdapter(Context context, List<Banner> banners) {

        this.banners = banners;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_header, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HeaderSliderAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(banners.get(position).getmSliderImage())) {
            holder.mSliderImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_img_ava);
            holder.mBackgroundImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(banners.get(position).getmSliderImage())
                    .fit()
                    .into(holder.mSliderImageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            holder.mBackgroundImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.tvWarningFailedtoLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.mSliderImageView.setClickable(true);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            holder.mBackgroundImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.tvWarningFailedtoLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.mSliderImageView.setClickable(false);

                        }
                    });
        }

       holder.mSliderImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               onClick.onItemCli(position, banners.get(position));
           }
       });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return banners.size(); }

        public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick) {
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }

    public interface OnItemClicked {
        void onItemCli(int position, Banner passData);
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView mSliderImageView,mBackgroundImage;
        public TextView tvWarningFailedtoLoad;
        public TextView tvTitle;

        View mView;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            mSliderImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.mSliderImage);
            mBackgroundImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
            tvWarningFailedtoLoad = mView.findViewById(R.id.tvFailedtoLoad);
            tvTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.mSliderImagetitle);
            tvTitle.setSelected(true);
            tvTitle.setSingleLine(true);

        }
    }

}
```

The error is getting in the below method.

```
holder.mSliderImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               onClick.onItemCli(position, banners.get(position));
           }
       });

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I gues that the clue to your issue is in the following part of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)):

> Note that unlike `ListView`, `RecyclerView` will not call this method again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only use the `position` parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep a copy of it. **If you need the position of an item later on (e.g. in a click listener), use `getAdapterPosition()` which will have the updated adapter position**. Override `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)` instead if Adapter can handle efficient partial bind.

So change the implementation of your `setOnClickListener()` method so it does not use the parametere `position`, but calls `getAdapterPosition()` instead to acquire the fresh value of your position.